# Unable to upload file in specific folder in google drive using REST API

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to upload a local file to a specified folder in Google Drive using REST API from android app, the file is uploading in the root directory but not uploading in the specified folder. No error in the API.

Using the following API:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#multipart

Tried passing the folder ID in metadata in following ways:

1.

```
String[] arr = {parentFolderId};    
jsonObject.put("parents", arr);
jsonObject.put("name", file.getName());
```

2. 

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
jsonObject1.put("id", parentFolderId);
jsonArray.put(jsonObject1);
jsonObject.put("parents", jsonArray);
jsonObject.put("name", file.getName());
```

3. 

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(); 
arrayList.add(parentFolderId);
jsonObject.put("parents", arrayList);
jsonObject.put("name", file.getName());
```

"parents" parameter isn't working, also tried using "addParents" parameter.
Kindly suggest a way to specify the parent folder ID.

Comment: In the future you should include the error message you are getting from these calls.

Comment: There is no error message in the API response

Comment: If there is no error message how do you know its not working?

Comment: The file is uploading in root directory and not the specified folder.

Comment: parse your object to json lets see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a java or android expert but this may get you started.

```
String folderId = "folderID";
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("FileName");
fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(folderId));

File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata)
.setFields("id, parent")
.execute();
System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```

or maybe this

```
String UploadFileToGoogleDrive(String sFullPath, String sFileName, String sParentFolderId) {               
    com.google.api.services.drive.model.File fileMetadata = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
    fileMetadata.setName(sFileName);
    fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(sParentFolderId));
    java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File(sFullPath);
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(null, filePath);
    try {
        com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = googleDriveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                .setFields("id, parents")
                .execute();
        return file.getId();
    } catch (IOException e) {            
        return null;
    }       
}
```

## pure rest html

Im not exactly usre what you mean by "I am using REST API." but if you are trying to do this completely yourself make sure that you build the body properly that is where the metadata is submited.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": "test",
  "parents": [
    "folderId"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have used "parents" parameter but its not working. I am not using SDK, I am using REST API.

Comment: i would print out your body. Sounds like the formatting isnt right if your not using the SDK.  I put in an edit of what the body is supposed to look like in raw json.

Comment: "parents": [
    "folderId"
  ]

I tried this but isn't working

Comment: Define "isnt working"

Comment: The file is uploading in root directory and not the specified folder.

Comment: What about the name of the file is that right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246228/discussion-between-mahesh-ambekar-and-daimto).